# creating a search feature in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a search feature for my back-end in Laravel 4 , where I can search for users by ( `firstname` , `lastname` , `email`). I have this function so far but it's not really working :

```
public function searchUser() 
{
    $search      = Input::get('search');
    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

    foreach($searchTerms as $term)
    {
        $query = User::Where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
    }

    $results = $query->get();
}
```

How do I get the others like `lastname`, `email` in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<?php

public function searchUser() 
{
    $search = Input::get('search');

    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

    $query = User::query();

    $fields = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');

    foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
        }
    }

    $results = $query->get();
}
```

This way it will do a LIKE query of all search terms in all fields.

You also can paginate it by doing:

```
$result = $query->paginate(10);
```

Comment: this will look for anything in the firstname , lastname and email? for example if I type : test it will look on these 3 columns in the database?

Comment: Yes, it will do a LIKE query of all search terms in all fields.

Comment: Yes! This is Laravel, you can do pretty much everything. :)

Comment: There should be `orWhere()`

Comment: You're absolutely right, deczo! And it's `User::query();`. Just tested in my end and it works fine. Edited.

Comment: but isnt there suppose to be an initial Where() then in the loop orWhere?

Comment: Laravel will take care about this for you, so no.

Comment: I have a problem with pagination , it seems like it doesnt keep the : $search = Input::get('search'); , when you click on the 2nd page? you know why? I have my routes get and post go to the searchUser() function

Comment: Yeah, that might be tricky, check this thread: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=479.

Comment: so I need to append the search to the links()?

Comment: There's many ways to tackle this, you can also store your search in a session variable...

Comment: what they mean by appends(array('search' => 'string'))? 'string' do I replace that with input value?

Comment: Take a look at the pagination docs: http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links

Comment: can I have the initial $query = User::query(); to be like a join ? like : $query = DB::table('users')
     ->join('roles' , 'users.role_id', '=' , 'roles.id')
     ->select('*' , 'users.id as user_id')
     ->where('roles.id' , '<>' , 0)
     ->orderBy($sort, $sort_dir);

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.

Comment: after the query, execute `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`, so it shows the generated SQL.

Comment: it looks ok , but i want it to search everything where role.id <> 0 , but its including the role.id = 0 , not sure why?

Comment: To help, people here will need to see your full query, but I think that in this case you should create a new question in StackOverflow, as they say `Please avoid extended discussions in comments.`

Comment: I figured it out , Thank you